# Ошибка при компиляции приложения Electron.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, electron

Сделал для примера простенькое electron.js приложение. На linux x64 компилируется отлично. А при компиляции на windows x64 выдаёт ошибку.

Команда:

```
sudo electron-packager . myApp --platform=win32 --arch=x64 --electron-version=1.8.4 --app-version=0.1.0 --out=dist --ignore=dist
```

Ошибка:

```
Packaging app for platform win32 x64 using electron v1.8.4
Could not find "wine" on your system.

Wine is required to use the appCopyright, appVersion, buildVersion, icon, and 
win32metadata parameters for Windows targets.

Make sure that the "wine" executable is in your PATH.

See https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-packager#building-windows-apps-from-non-windows-platforms for details.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! app@0.1.0 build: `sudo electron-packager . myApp --platform=win32 --arch=x64 --electron-version=1.8.4 --app-version=0.1.0 --out=dist --ignore=dist`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the app@0.1.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/dima/.npm/_logs/2018-04-13T22_45_05_870Z-debug.log
```

В чём проблема то? Буду благодарен любому ответу.

Comment: Так а wine-то установлен?

Comment: Нет походу. А какой командой его установить можно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### во первых

> На linux x64 компилируется отлично. А при компиляции на windows x64 выдаёт ошибку

можно понять как:

- компиляция на машине с ОС linux - отлично
- компиляция на машине с ОС linux - выдаёт ошибку

а можно предположить что речь идёт о флагах `--platform=win32 --arch=x64`

### во вторых предлагаю вариант без компиляции

> https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/application-distribution
>
> Для распространения вашего приложения с Electron, вам нужно скачать [предварительно собранные двоичные файлы](https://github.com/electron/electron/releases) Electron.

например `electron-v2.0.0-beta.7-linux-x64.zip`

> Далее папку, содержащую ваше приложение следует назвать app и поместить в каталог ресурсов Electron

имеется ввиду ваше JS приложение

```
electron/resources/app
  ├── package.json
  ├── main.js
  └── index.html
```

в папке `resources` архив `electron-v2.0.0-beta.7-linux-x64.zip` содержит:

- default_app.asar
- electron.asar

`asar` это что-то вроде `zip`
`electron` может работать как с `asar` так и с обычными папками

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего, проблема в том, что в системе не установлен wine. Wine позволяет запускать *.exe в linux, electron-packager использует его для сборки.
Можно поставить так:

```
sudo apt install wine-stable
```